# How to put Facebook URL graph API into a specific variable and echo it out using php language?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I was trying to put the value inside a variable, but I was having a hard time finding tutorials in google. Maybe someone could help me finding the solution.

```
  <?php
   require_once __DIR__ . '/graphSDK/src/Facebook/Facebook.php'; 
   require_once __DIR__ .'/graphSDK/src/Facebook/autoload.php';


   $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '204902076724611',
    'app_secret' => 'a38fb1ef6db1caca2f5cbc5314defdfd',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11'
  ]);

  try {
    $response = $fb->get('/764215210440736/feed?
    fields=comments{comments{message,from},message,from},message,from');
   $page = $response->getGraphEdge();
    print_r('<pre>'.$page.'<pre>');
  }

} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

What I really want is how do I fetch specific fields on the facebook for example the comment_id and message, I put them inside a variable and then echo them out. Can anyone help me?

[This is the result after using the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhTME.png)

Comment: Hard to say, as you've left some of the response structure out, but you'll be able to do something like `foreach($page->comments as $comment) {` - it's just a nested set of objects.

Comment: can you give me an example so I could try it out @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

As writed in the comments you can do a `foreach()` loop to iterate over the JSON response array from graph API.

example:

`foreach($page->comments as $comment): $message = $comment['message']; $messageID = $comment['comment_id']; endforech;`

Remember to respect the structure of the JSON response. If I remember well, on the graph api documentations there are some example on how to iterate over the api response.